# UISwitch latency between taps caused by Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswitch

I have a view with a bunch of UISwitch.

My problem is that when I tap on a switch I need to wait about 10 seconds before being able to tap any other switch of the view.

Here is my code :

```
-(void) didTapSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"BEGIN didTapSwitch, %@",sender);
    DADudesManager *dudesManager = [DADudesManager getInstance];
    DADude *updatedDude = [dudesManager.dudesList objectAtIndex:[[self.spendingDudesTableView indexPathForCell:sender.superview.superview] row]];
    DAAccountManager *accountManager = [DAAccountManager getInstance];
    [accountManager.accountsOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"BACKGROUND OPERATION BEGINS switchDudeBeneficiates, %@",sender);
        DASpendingsManager *spendingsManager = [DASpendingsManager getInstance];
        [[spendingsManager.spendingObserver childByAppendingPath:self.spending.spendingID] updateChildValues:@{updatedDude.dudeName: [sender isOn] ? @"1" : @"0"}];
        NSLog(@"BACKGROUND OPERATION ENDS switchDudeBeneficiates, %@",sender);
    }];
    NSLog(@"END switchDudeBeneficiates, %@",sender);
}
```

My `spendingObserver` is a Firebase object initiated before.

When the code above is executed, the NSLogs show almost instantaneously in the console, the data is updated online at the same time, but the switches don't react to any tap for another 9 to 11 secs.

Of course commenting the line `[[spendingsManager.spendingObserver childByAppendingPath:self.spending.spendingID] updateChildValues:@{weakDude.dudeName: [weakSwitch isOn] ? @"1" : @"0"}];` removes the latency, so the problem must come from Firebase, but I have no clue what's going on.

I am probably missing something obvious as I'm pretty new to IOS development !

Comment: There isn't enough code here to reproduce the error. This references Firebase as the issue, but I can't see enough context of how Firebase is being employed to understand where and how it is being utilized. A simple repro will probably be necessary to assist.

Answer (score 0):

I can think couple of reasons.

1. You are sending the PayLoad in the main thread, which is causing the User INterface events to be suspended.
2. The code you ran, might be linked to other functions in the library you are using, that might be causing the lag.

TRY - >
 try putting your code in an NSOperation and execute that. Or use GCD to do work on different thread just not the UI thread which is the main thead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just tried with GCD with a different thread, and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: I thought about the linking problem and tried to put weak references of my variables `sender ` and `updatedDude ` in the block but it didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

Step back and simplify. Make your switch code simply log the change in value. NSLog includes a timestamp, so you can tell when the switch events occur.

If do-nothing code responds quickly, as I suspect it will, then add log statements at the beginning and end of your switch action method. That way you can see if there is a delay between the beginning and end of the processing.

You could also run the app in instruments (time  profiler) and see where your app is spending time.

Comment: Thanks. Like I said in my question, the logs clearly show that the function states it's done almost immediately after tapping the switch.  So the function seems to be quick enough, and from the logs, the lag does not come from the function. But of course the lags comes from the function because when I comment out the line calling Firebase, everything works as it is supposed to work. This Firebase must block something, but I have no idea what.